# Ionic 2 redirect to another page after app boot

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to redirect page to home page (override login page) when it already has token on localStorage. How to do it? I have following code on constructor() at app.component.ts, but it display login first before request completed

```
statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#D32F2F');
      splashScreen.hide();
      if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
        authProvider.silent_login().subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
          if(res.error==0){
            this.rootPage = HomePage;
          }
        })
      }
```

Comment: I think you also set rootPage before constructor() right?

Comment: Yes, that i want. But i never mind how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you like

```
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
    rootPage: any = null; // Initialize it as null
    pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

    constructor(public platform: Platform, 
                public statusBar: StatusBar, 
                public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
                public commonProvider: CommonProvider) {

        this.commonProvider.retrieve("is_login").then(loggedIn => {
            // Assign the right page after checking the status
            this.rootPage = loggedIn ? TabsPage : SigninPage;
        });
     }
```

Comment: Np :) I always use a similar approach when I need to decide which page should be shown at start. I think this answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yah right approach. Appreciate. I am going to use this in project.

Comment: @PareshGami Thanks for the solution. It works perfectly.

Comment: @sebaferreras Thanks for the edit. It so simple than creating a new splash page

Answer (score 0):

The solution is generate one page named splash and set root page of app to it and at constructor, we check the token. If fails set root page to login and if success set root page to homepage.

I think thats the only solution. Splash page as credentials checker.

Maybe it helps other